# Socket.IO handling multi-player movement in open-world

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io, multiplayer

I am building a multi-player server for an open-world game I am building using Unity 5. I've chosen Socket.IO to be the real-time framework as I know it more than any other real-time framework.

How can I store each active player's socket in a way which would allow me to sort out each player by their distance from a cord. (for example, to only update a moving players position to players who are nearby rather than sending out to all the players on the server)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a data structure issue to me. A simple way that comes to mind would be to have:

**Zones** - this is a regional breakdown of space in the game
**Player** - this represents an individual playing
**Socket** - the means to communicate to a given player

The Player should have a reference to the Socket to communicate. `player.SendMessage("hey there");`

A zone should have a list of players

```
zonePlayers = new List<Player> Players();
```

if a message is to be broadcast through the entire zone simply iterate over the player list and send that message to each player.

```
foreach (Player player in Players) {
  player.SendMessage(msg);
}
```

Figure out how to send a message to a player.
Figure out how to logically group players together.

I just read about Socket.IO and they already have Rooms. If you define a room per zone and just have a player register for that room and leave that room when they entire / leave the zone - you can utilize already built in functionality for messaging the group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I've ended up creating a method which sorts through all the players, grabs their X/Y/Z and only returns the ones within a distance specified by a parameter in the method. I can then send an update to all of those players. Is that practical?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable start. If it becomes the bottleneck you'll be in a situation where you have a good problem to deal with (too many players / too large a world)

If you're iterating through all players every time a message is sent that does sound unnecessary though.